# DRF Django: How to modify a value before saving

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

```
class Pet(models.Model):
    date_of_birth = models.DateField()

class PetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Pet
        fields = "__all__"
```

Now when i trying to do

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
 -d '{
"date_of_birth":"2021-08-29T00:46:27.103Z"
}' http://localhost:8025/api/dob/
```

I get

```
{"date_of_birth":["Date has wrong format. Use one of these formats instead: YYYY-MM-DD."]}
```

How to manage this because i will get input as `2021-08-29T00:46:27.103Z` format only

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `input_formats` to your date field:

```py
class PetSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    date_of_birth = serializers.DateField(input_formats=['%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ'])

    class Meta:
        model = Pet
        fields = ('date_of_birth', ...)
```

Docs in https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#datefield

Comment: but this will save in the postgresql as `'2021-08-29'::date`

Comment: Its datetime, i only want date to be stored. I am not sure. I think it will store as  '2021-08-29'::date

Comment: `...` will that add all other fields

Comment: Its a `datetime.date` type object. It has just date, Isn't it what you want ? @Santhosh